# Read an excel(.xlsx) file stored in the project folder using excelJS library in React

Tags: reactjs, excel, typeerror, readfile, exceljs

**Scenario:**
I pre-populated an excel file an stored it inside my package folder. On clicking the download button a function will be called where the existing file should be read and add the required rows and start the download.

**My project Tree**

```
|Package A
   |public(folder)
      |data.xlsx(excel file) 
   |src(folder)
      |helpers
         | ReportGenerator.ts(ts file) ->file where the required function is written.
```

**Code written inside ReportGenerator.ts**

```
const Excel = require("exceljs");
export function GenerateReport() {
  const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  workbook.xlsx.readFile("public/data.xlsx).then(function(data:any) {
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  });
}
```

Ideally, it should have read the file...

**Problem Facing:**
At line where trying to read the file i.e workbook.xlsx.readFile(//path).then without entering the function it is throwing an error at the console **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.constants is undefined**

Please guide me with the correct approach..Thanks in advance